# Where do URI files come from?

Tags: themes, paths

Installed locally or in a web server, how is a file (for example, style.css using `wp_enqueue_style`) created?

More specifically, when I tried this using the default twentythirteen theme:

```
 echo get_stylesheet_uri();
```

I get this: `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css`.

So I thought of trying to go to `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-content` but was surprised that nothing comes out. However going to the stylesheet URI will bring out the stylesheet.

Where's the server keeping this file?

Another related question would be:

```
 echo get_theme_root().'twentythirteen/style.css';
```

VS

```
 echo get_stylesheet_uri();
```

I know the above is a directory while the one below is the URI example I've given above, but how are they different in terms of linking content of the file itself?

Comment: The gap you are trying to bridge here is not related to wordpress but understanding how URLs are mapped to file by the webserver. You assume there is a 1:1 mapping but it is a wrong assumption

Comment: Could you please clarify your actual question? Answer to _Where's the server keeping this file?_ is, well, somewhere. It depends. As your earlier question this is about basic web server mechanics first and how WP handles it second.

Comment: "Directory Listing" is disabled on many (most) public facing servers as it is rarely necessary and is a security issue. That is why you don't see anything at `/wp-content`. WordPress additionally adds dummy `index.php` files to numerous directories just in case. This isn't really a WordPress issue though. Perhaps if you could explain ___why___ you are asking the question?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Why I am asking this question is actually found in another related question I've asked here, with no answer. To repeat that question, I was asking why WP's wp_enqueue_style/script function uses a URL instead of just a DIR, while 'including' uses DIR instead of URL (if they are pointing to the same file).

Comment: @Bobby : [your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124957/21376) has two answers, one of which is _accepted_ and both are correct. This is not a WordPress question. You are fundamentally confused about the basics of how a server operates.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Sorry for posting this topic twice, but I really don't know how to go about googling this, can you suggest some keywords that might help? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to "Google"? [Your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124957/21376) has two answers, ___one of which is accepted and both are correct___.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. I just want to do more research on this topic, which you are clearly not helping but constantly banging on the fact that I may have asked a very 'noob' question. The accepted answer only answered what I asked but to understand further WHY a WordPress or as a matter of fact, the basic operations of a server needs to link the same file in the form of DIR or URL, WHEN to use which has not been answered (@second answer, what exactly is 'insecure', 'poorly'?, etc)